# Angular 2 Reactive Forms - Validate Fields After User Has Left Field

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

By default the validators in a model driven form (such as the one below) fire on every key stroke in an input field.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'username': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
        'email': ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

Is there a way to run the validators after the user has left the field only?

Comment: *Has Left Field* means *On Blur*?

Comment: @PankajParkar yep

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866824/angular2-control-validation-on-blur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Control Validation on blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866824/angular2-control-validation-on-blur)