# input placeholder issue on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

I am new to `angular 2` and `angular 4` . I have just converted my application from 2 to 4. So, here I am facing an issue , **On IE11, when receives focus, placeholder is removed and form control is set to dirty and pristine is set to false. On chrome / FF, this issue never occurs.**

My Html is like -

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="processName" 
                         [(ngModel)]="process.displayName" [disabled]="isProcessLoading"
                         #processName="ngModel" maxLength="64" pattern="^.*\S.*" name="processName"
 placeholder="{{'PROCESS-FORM.name-placeholder' | translate}}" required
                         placeholderRequired [inputBinding]="processName"/>
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening ? Thanks in the advance .

Comment: Use the Emulation tab of IE's dev tools to find out which IE Emulation mode (aka documentMode) your site is using.

Comment: Removing the placeholder text on focus is default IE11 behaviour. Just checked with IE11 on Windows 10. You can try for yourself [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue , You can find it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433804/angular-4-0-0-model-driven-forms-input-placeholder-issue-on-ie11