# Angular 2 - How to bind a Reactive form element to an event dynamically?

Tags: angular

Suppose I create a reactive form like the following:

```js
public form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({ myControl: new FormControl() });
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically (from code and not template) bind the control to an event. Something like this:

```
this.form.controls['myControl'].bind('blur', someMethod());
```

How is it possible with Angular 2?

Comment: Check [Control Validation on blur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41973780/2435473)

Answer (score -2):

You can call a function for that form control like

```
<textarea #urlcontent formControlName="content" (blur)="validateEmbedUrl(urlcontent.value)"></textarea>
```

Comment: I meant from TypeScript code. Not from the template.