# Angular 2 event listeners condition race

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, race-condition

I have a directive `appValidateOnChange` that implements

```
@HostListener('focus') onFocus() {
    this.validators = this.formControl.control.validator;
    this.asyncValidators = this.formControl.control.asyncValidator;
    this.formControl.control.clearAsyncValidators();
    this.formControl.control.clearValidators();
}
@HostListener('change') onChange() {
    this.formControl.control.setAsyncValidators(this.asyncValidators);
    this.formControl.control.setValidators(this.validators);
    this.formControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

The goal is to wait for the user to finish his input before validating it. I'm calling it simply like this

```
<input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="field"
        name="field"
        [ngModel]="fieldValue"
        #fieldName="ngModel"
        required
        minlength="8"
        (change)="updateField(fieldName)"
        appValidateOnChange>
```

In the `updateField` function I have

```
if(!field.valid)
    return false;
```

The problem is, there is a race condition between the two `change` events.

Sometimes everything works as intended, because the directive's event triggers first, and some other times validation is ignored, since the directive's event triggers second.

How can I resolve that? I would like to avoid `setTimeout`.

Comment: Could you check the validity of the data on the forms submission instead of live?

Comment: have you tried putting a HostListener to the `input` event instead of the `change` event in the directive or the input? that way you would have a  different event inside your directive and in `updateField`, instead of 2 listeners of the same event

Comment: @Cacoon I would have loved to do that, sadly the specs of this project excludes forms - updates must be triggered as soon as user changes something (I hate it, tbh)

Comment: @OsmanCea I tried with `blur` event but it goes after `change` event and I absolutely need the update function to be called on change, not blur... The `input` event, if I'm not mistaken, triggers each time you enter a key, right ? If so it's not a good fit as validation would trigger after the first keystroke, which is not what I attend to accomplish

Comment: Would it be possible to move the change in component to a service that directive would run as soon as it finished onChange()? So you are sure to run both changes in the order you wish?

Comment: @Vega that could be a solution, I guess... But usually you don't want to delegate to a directive anything to do with the controller. I could do that if no other option appears, though. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded to Angular 5, a new feature was added to validate only on `blur`, example:

```html
<input name="firstName" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

I refer you to the documentation look under the heading **Angular Forms adds updateOn Blur / Submit**

https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced

Comment: Ok, that seemed very interesting, so I tried to upgrade... But encountered countless problems. There are bugs in the update way, some of my 3rd party components are not yet compatible, etc... I don't think I will be able to use Angular 5 immediately

Answer (score 1):

I would just not show the validation result while the control has the focus and completly ignore when the default validation is happening.

Use the focus and blur events to set/clear a flag and hide the validation warning while the flag is set (using `*ngIf` or `[hidden]="myFlag"`

Comment: But that would add 2 more event listeners by field, won't it hurt performances ? Also, I don't want validation to be displayed initially, only after the user took the pristine out of the field... I could adapt this, I guess. Initially I adapted from the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866824/angular2-formcontrol-validation-on-blur

Comment: You already have 2 event listeners. You wouldn't need to add more. It wouldn't affect performance anyway.

Comment: It's working pretty well. Not exactly what I was looking for but that will do, for now. I will probably try to update Angular to 5.0 and try again the other solution that has been given to me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use ngModelChange instead of change, as you use ngModel,
then directive is always fired first:
**HTML**

```
<input myDirective
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="field"
        name="field"
        [ngModel]="fieldValue"
        #fieldName="ngModel"
        required
        minlength="8"
        (ngModelChange)="updateField(fieldName)"
        appValidateOnChange>
```

**Directive**

```
@HostListener('ngModelChange') onChange() {
  console.log("onChange fired")
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vjqfq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, that's not bad at all... I'm still pulling away from using this directive by taking one of the two first answers, but your solution seems to work - I tested 3 times and it was always the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with template driven form. With reactive from you could do this:

template:

`<input formControlName="myName" (blur)="update('myName')">`

component:

```
update(name: string) {
    this.form.controls[name].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with template driven forms, sadly ! Thanks for the idea.