# Angular reactive forms add custom Validation onBlur

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the OnBlur syntax correct but it is eluding me.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      published: true,
      credentials: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [this.isNameDuplicate(this.form)]],
      password: '',
    }));
  }

  isNameDuplicate(form:FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    const userNames = this.form.get("credentials").value;
    console.log(userNames);
    const names = userNames.map(item=> item.username.trim());
    const hasDuplicate = names.some(
    (name, index) => names.indexOf(name, index + 1) != -1
  );

     if (hasDuplicate) {
       console.log(hasDuplicate);
       return { duplicate: true };
     }

     return null;
    }
  } 
}
```

I have to make sure that the isNameDuplicate validator fires onblur but the syntax is eluding me.

Can i get some help please.

My try

```
addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      username: ['', {
      validators:[this.isNameDuplicate(this.form)],
      updateOn:'blur'}],
      password: '',
    }));
  }
```

But i get an error saying isNameDuplicate does not exist on the component.

Comment: Checkout " 'blur'  " in https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn

Comment: also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866824/angular2-formcontrol-validation-on-blur

Comment: Hi from the docs it is not clear to me racraman and also in the duplicate SO post the syntax is different i am using formBuilder not the formControl syntax

Comment: you don't pass this.form as parameter in function  this.isNameDuplicate()..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using

```
addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      username: ['', {
      validators:[this.isNameDuplicate(this.form)],
      updateOn:'blur'}],
      password: '',
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component's HTML file user blur event like follows:-

```
<input (blur)="callSOmeFunction()">


callSOmeFunction(){
sampleForm.valid
}
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth i wanted that as a validation method which fires on blur.